Is this differential operator self-adjoint?
If $V$ is the space of functions in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x)=f(x+2)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}.$ Equipping $V$ with the inner product of the space $C[-1,1]$, is the operator $D:f\mapsto f''$ self adjoint?
In this case the inner product is clearly $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx=\langle f,g\rangle$. How can I use the previosly mentioned property of functions in $V$ to determine whether $D=D^*$ holds or not

Integration by parts twice.

You want to show $$\langle f'',g\rangle=\langle f,g''\rangle.$$ You can prove that both are $-\langle f',g'\rangle$ by integration by parts.

Thanks! Will try this idea later and see if I can arrive yo the desired result
